# Can't play a sound with a space in the (NSURL *)sound_url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tweak

I want to play a sound like this:

```
#define url(x) [NSURL URLWithString:x]
....

AVAudioPlayer *myFatBeat;
myFatBeat = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url(@"/Library/Ringtones/Bell% Tower.m4r") error:nil];
[myFatBeat setNumberOfLoops:-1];  
[myFatBeat play];
```

but it fails. I think it's due to the space between `Bell`and `Tower`, as it works if the sound name is `Àlarm`. Then, I tried to escape the sound name like this `Bell\ Tower`, but I get `error: unknown escape sequence: '\040'` when compiling.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot if this is how you do it in an `NSUrl`, but you can try `%20` instead of the space.

```
myFatBeat = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]     
initWithContentsOfURL:url(@"/Library/Ringtones/Bell%20Tower.m4r") error:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

Encode your URL first:

```
#define url(x) [NSURL URLWithString:[x stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
```