# iOS AVPlayer not streaming URL with spaces

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio-streaming, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to stream audio in iOS, it is streaming http://www.pragitec.com/SMCONTENT/117-ideas-and-tips-to-organize-your-business-life/Track1-Introduction.wav but not http://www.pragitec.com/SMCONTENT/100-words-to-sound-smarter/01 Track - Introduction.wav, I tried

```
NSString *urlString=(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)[_linkArr objectAtIndex:count], NULL, (CFStringRef)@"", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

and 

NSString *urlString =[[_linkArr objectAtIndex:count] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; but no use. After encode resulting URL is something like this
```

http://www.pragitec.com/SMCONTENT/100-words-to-sound-smarter/01%20Track%20-%20Introduction.wav
 it is playing in browser but not in my app... Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't play a sound with a space in the (NSURL \*)sound\_url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165539/cant-play-a-sound-with-a-space-in-the-nsurl-sound-url)

Comment: I tried that... its not working and it is AVPlayer not AVAudioplayer

Comment: Once you get the modified URL you can try replacing '%20' character with simply @""string.

Comment: why don't you use MPMoviePlayerController? It can stream audio from URL.